# How to deserialize list JSON using entity class?

Tags: json, asp.net-core, json-deserialization

I am getting a JSON in which it include list. Now I want to use only some property rather than all the properties.
JSON

```
{ 
  "instance_pools" : [
      {
          "instance_pool_name":"pool1",
          "node_type_id":"standard",
          "azure_attributes":{
              "availability":"on"
           },
           "instance_pool_id":"poool2345",
           "status":{}
      },
      {
          "instance_pool_name":"pool1",
          "node_type_id":"normal",
          "azure_attributes":{
              "availability":"on"
           },
           "instance_pool_id":"poool2345",
           "status":{}
      },
      {
          "instance_pool_name":"pool1",
          "node_type_id":"high",
          "azure_attributes":{
              "availability":"on"
           },
           "instance_pool_id":"poool2345",
           "status":{}
      }
  ]
}
```

Now at .Net side, I only want instance_pool_name and corresponding instance_pool_id.
I am new to .Net, Can somebody please help me with how to deserialize this complex JSON and use only some properties.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the classes as you want. You must not map all json properties into C# class' property. Therefore you can write the C# classes with the properties you need:

```
public class InstancePoolCollection
{
    public InstancePool[] instance_pools{get;set;}
}


public class InstancePool
{
    public string instance_pool_id{get;set;}
    public string instance_pool_name{get;set;}
}
```

##### Deserializing using System.Text

```
var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<InstancePoolCollection>(jsonObj);
```

##### Deserializing using Newtonsoft.Json

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InstancePoolCollection>(jsonObj);
```

> Note: Your JSON was not conform. I have changed it.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, Can i ask one more thing. Now var obj contain all the values. But If I want to find **instance_pool_id** for **node_type_id** standard and save that into another variable. Then how should i access var obj

Comment: If you need the node_type_id as property then you need to add this property to InstancePool class too. After that you can use LINQ on the deserialized collection. e.g. `var item = obj.SingleOrDefault(e => e.node_type_id.Equals("standard"));`